# Export /Import single class from Ez publish 5

Tags: ezpublish

From where i can Export /Import single class from Ez publish 5? i can`t found it , if someone know about it please  link me DOC  or  show me a screen shot of directory in ez publish 5.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can export and import classes and content objects in administration interface under the `/package/list` link.

There are two options, "Create new package" for exporting and "Import new package" for importing.

The process is fairly trivial, so just follow on screen instructions and you should be set.